# Error (in R): Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following **code**:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(complete.cases(B)) %>% 
  mutate(A = unique(df$A)) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% select(A), ., by = "A")
```

in which A is a column with 1.048.575 observations that comes from one Excel file, and B is a column with 10.571 observations that comes from another Excel file.

This code works just fine for a **data** sample like this:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
), B = c(4193, 15, 9734, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

As can be seen below, what I need is to match each unique observation in B with a series of repeated observations in A, and this code gives me the following, desired **output**:

```
   A    B
1  1 4193
2  1 4193
3  1 4193
4  1 4193
5  1 4193
6  1 4193
7  1 4193
8  2   15
9  2   15
10 2   15
11 3 9734
12 3 9734
13 3 9734
14 3 9734
```

However, my problem comes from the fact that *this sample output consists of two columns of equal length, whereas the dataset I am working with has two columns of unequal length*, and which needs to be structured in one way or the other, so that all observations are included.

I have structured my **data** like this:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(rep(list(1048575))
), B = c(rep(list(10571)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(-10571L, -1048575L))
```

But when I try to run the same code, I get the *error message* "Error: Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size."

Does anyone know how can I override the problem I am having (whether by structuring data in a different way or by trying out another code), so that the code can be run for all the needed observations?

P.S.

Another **code** that I have tried has been the following one:

```
library(dplyr)

df_A <- df %>%
  dplyr::count(A)

vector_A <- df_A[,2]

vector_B <- df$B

Result <- rep(vector_A, vector_B)
```

However, this last approach has got me nowhere.

I sincerely hope that I have been clear enough in explaining the problem I am having.

Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Given output when running @RonakShah code:

```
            A          B
-10571  <dbl [1]>   <dbl [1]>       
-1048575 <NULL>     <dbl [1]>
```

Comment: If the column A had values 1,2,3 and the column B had values 10,20, what would your expected output be?

Comment: Thank you, I understand the gist of your question, but the thing is that all values present in column B are contained in column A. So the desired output is the same as stated in my question. I hope this information is useful, in case you could possibly help me. Thanks once again!

Comment: When creating `df` after *I  have structured my **data** like this:* I get a warning. Please provide the data without producing a warning. Two columns of unequal length can not be stored in a `data.frame`.

Comment: Oh, I see... I am relatively new to R and I didn't know this. Many thanks indeed for pointing this out to me, @GKi! I am not sure how I could provide you the data without producing a warning then, since this is really the kit of the question that I'm having. Would you know, by chance, how can I store my data differently, so I can work with it? Maybe it could be done in the form of a list, but then this would rule out the option of working with dplyr, since it requires the data to be in the form of a data.frame. Hmmm... :-/

Comment: @Gki Thanks once again for your time and your useful comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(B = na.omit(B)[match(A, unique(A))])
df

#   A    B
#1  1 4193
#2  1 4193
#3  1 4193
#4  1 4193
#5  1 4193
#6  1 4193
#7  1 4193
#8  2   15
#9  2   15
#10 2   15
#11 3 9734
#12 3 9734
#13 3 9734
#14 3 9734
```

`match(.., unique(..))` constructs a sequential index for each unique value of `A`. We then use it to subset the non-NA values of `B`.

For this example, since the `A` values are 1, 2, 3 in sequence you can use this directly.

```
df %>% mutate(B = na.omit(B)[A])
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, Ronak! However, when I run your code, I get the following output:
                               A              B
-10571        <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  
-1048575 <NULL> <dbl [1]> 

I think there is something wrong with the way I have structured the data (as posted in the question). I am not sure if you could help me out with seeing the way I could structure it correctly. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Still I don't know exactly what is wanted but giving also here a simple example and hoping it comes closer to the desired result.

```
#Data with two columns of unequal length
l <- list(A = c(3,3,3,2,2,1), B = c(4,5,6))

#Expand B to length of A using rep and rle
data.frame(l["A"], B = rep(l$B, rle(l$A)$lengths))
#  A B
#1 3 4
#2 3 4
#3 3 4
#4 2 5
#5 2 5
#6 1 6
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This is exactly what I meant and what I was looking for. However, I've got just one small problem: when trying to use my list instead of the sample that you provided, I get the warning ```Error in rle(l$A) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type```. I've checked whether ```l$A``` is of an atomic type, and it is. I have tried using ```unlist```, but this has been of no help. I am really not sure why I am getting this warning then, and how I can solve this issue. I am very grateful for your help, and I am really sorry for bothering you once again.

Comment: What does `str(l$A)` show?

Comment: Thanks once again for your response! It shows ```NULL```.

Comment: Do you a column named `A` in list `l`?

Comment: Yes, sure, ```A``` is in list ```l```.

Comment: What do so get when typing `l$A` ?

Comment: It says ```NULL``` again. Which I don't get, since it is an imported column from ```X```, which should contain data, and which I get in the output (in the form of a matrix) when I type just ```A```.

Comment: By ```X``` I mean the Excel file from which I am importing the data.

Comment: OK. You have to provide data on the paces where I used `l["A"]` or `l$A` and `l$B`.

Comment: I have just modified the way I had structured the list, and now I do get the needed output when I type ```l$A``` or ```l$B```, so it seems that all data is correctly contained. However, I now get the warning ```invalid 'times' argument``` in ```data.frame(l["A"], B = rep(l$B, rle(l$A)$lengths))```.

Comment: Looks like that `l$B` has not the same length like `rle(l$A)$lengths`. So your data has a different structure than the data I have used. Maybe `l$A` contains `NA`?

Comment: Hello again, @Gki! No, ```l$A``` does not contain any ```NA```s. These are all real ordered numbers, from 1 to 10.571. I do not understand why I get this error, since I am following exactly the same approach that you've used in your sample data example, faced with the problem of having two columns of unequal length (A contains 1.048.575 observations and B contains 10.571 ones). ```l$B``` does contain some ```0```s, but I don't think that is a problem, since ```0``` is a real number also. Come what may, you have been of great help already, so I don't want to take any more of your valuable time.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help! I did not get to where I wanted to get with my data, but your comments have certainly helped me learn more about the way R works, and I am very grateful to you for this.

Comment: What do yu get from `length(l$B)` and what from `length(rle(l$A)$lengths)`? They should be equal.