# rep(x, each=y) gives incomplete output in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run the following **code**:

```
X <- data.frame(X)
Y <- data.frame(Y)

library(dplyr)

df_v1 <- X %>%
  dplyr::count(v1)

vector_v1 <- df_v1[,2]

vector_v2 <- Y$v2

Result <- rep(vector_v2, each=vector_v1)

print(Result)
```

I have a total of 1.048.575 observations in `v1` and by using `dplyr::count(v1)`, I am trying to see how many of them (these are integers ordered in ascending number, from 1 to 10.571) are repeated. The output that I get is `n: 45, 68, 37, 41 ...` .

Then, by using `rep(vector_v2, each=vector_v1)`, I am trying to match (or, rather, to fill in) 10571 observations that I have in `v2` with the amount of repeated observations that I have in `v1`, and store them in the variable `Result`.

The **output** that I get is, as follows:

```
first element used of 'each' argument   [1] 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716
  [18] 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716
  [35] 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 1716 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184
  [52] 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184
  [69] 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184
  [86] 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558
 [103]  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558
 [120]  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558  558 2254
 [137] 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254
 [154] 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254
 [171] 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 2254 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719
 [188] 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719
 [205] 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719 4719
```

which is all fine by me, with the exception of the fact that I obtain a total of 475.695, instead of the desired 1.048.575 observations.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Also, I would ideally like to have the output in the form of one single column instead of a matrix. Any idea on how this could be achieved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try using the function `uncount` and see what happens

Comment: From the online doc for `rep`: "each: non-negative *integer*. Each element of x is repeated each times."  (my emphasis).  You're passing it a vector.  I suspect that's where your problem lies, and the warning message is your clue.

Comment: If the items are not all sorted you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Use `rep(vector_v2, vector_v1)` instead of `rep(vector_v2, each=vector_v1)`

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for your suggestion! The problem, though, is that I am working with a very large vector, and I get a warning saying that "large vectors are not currently supported yet" when trying to use ```uncount``` function.

Comment: @GKi Thank you for your suggestion! I tried this option already and it didn't work.

Comment: Then maybe: `rep_len(vector_v2, sum(vector_v1))` ?

Comment: Thank you, @GKi! This does give me the needed 1.048.575 observations, but the issue with this code is that they are not repeated in a sequence, as illustrated in the output included in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get how the output should look like, so make a simple example showing the output.

```
v1 <- 4:6
v2 <- 1:3

rep(v1, v2)
#[1] 4 5 5 6 6 6

rep_len(v1, sum(v2))
#[1] 4 5 6 4 5 6

#gives a WARNING, that only the first element of v2 is used
rep(v1, each=v2)
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: I am sorry for not having been clear enough... this is a different approach that I've tried, since I haven't been able to come up with a solution in this other question that I asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000646/error-in-r-internal-error-in-df-slice-columns-must-match-the-data-frame . If you check it out, you will find an example there and you will also easily see what I am trying to achieve. Many thanks for your time and your patience!